# htaccess redirect not working in Chrome or other browsers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am hosting a separate site in a subfolder. The rules I have set up in my .htaccess file are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

This works fine in Firefox (example.com redirects to www.example.com), but not in any other browser.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I've cleared cache, etc., but the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

I apologize, I should have explained better. There are two sites here, one for the main folder and one for the subfolder. Full htaccess file is below.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainsite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mainsite.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.secondarysite.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} secondarysite.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

The first chunk is for the main site, the second for the secondary site, pointing to the subfolder.

Comment: Er... what part would redirect to another hostname?

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep only one Condition and tell me if it worked :

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Then add your lines :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subfolder/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! You mean remove the subfolder call?

Comment: Remove it and try, to locate the problem

Comment: Just tried your rules, it seems to be working across browsers.

Comment: Then add your subfolder lines after mines, and tell me again what happens

Comment: Ah, the problem with this is it ignores the main site. Apologies! See the original question with edits.